# Xamarin App Sends Json Data When Phone Virtual But Doesn't Send Physical

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I don't know where to look or what to check but ask my question in title. Xamarin forms app works when sending json data over virtual phone instance but doesn't send data over physical no matter which platform i use , it is the same with iOS and Android.

```
        static async Task phoneInfo()
        {
        string url = "http://blabla.com/api/blabla";
        string sContentType = "application/json";
        JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceModel", DeviceInfo.Model);
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceManufacturer", DeviceInfo.Manufacturer);
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceName", DeviceInfo.Name);
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceVersion", DeviceInfo.VersionString);
        jsonObject.Add("DevicePlatform", DeviceInfo.Platform);
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceIdiom", DeviceInfo.Idiom);
        jsonObject.Add("DeviceType", DeviceInfo.DeviceType.ToString());
        jsonObject.Add("AreaOne", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
        jsonObject.Add("Deleted", false);
        HttpClient oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var oTaskPostAsync = await oHttpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));
        }
```

usage is simple like code. just put await phoneInfo(); where i want to take info.

i have accesswifistate and internet permission over Android and NSAppTransportSecurity for non https connection with iOS.

Any ideas where am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you attempting to catch any exceptions?  Are you sure the remote url is accessible from the device? (test using the in-device browser).  Is the problem that the connection is not being made, or that it IS being made but the data is not being sent?

Comment: in virtual phone yeah i have exceptions. it says 201 created. and url is accessible over physical phone. i don't know which one is my exception. connection lost or data is not sending. and i don't know how to catch exception in realtime phone.

Comment: Without any additional debug info this will be a hard one to figure out. Does the XCode Console give you any additional info? You can find it in XCode here: Window -> Devices and Simulators. The window that pops up allows you to open the device logs and start the Console application. The Console application shows debugging information that are being streamed from the device in real-time.

Comment: you are getting exceptions when testing in the emulator?  Maybe you should try fixing those first?  You can debug on a device in the same way you do on the emulator.

Comment: emmm thanks for your answer Michael C. but i am using Visual Studio For Mac. Never tried Xcode.

Comment: thank you Jason. but no. i am not getting any error. it works perfectly on virtual machines.

Comment: you need to step through the code with the debugger and monitor what it is doing

Comment: i did that Jason. but as i told you i see no error on virtual phone.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-device?tabs=vswin

Comment: @Erdinç Even if you are not using XCode to write your code. Xamarin.Forms uses it to deploy your app and you can use its debugging tools like the Console which gives you real-time error reporting. I have found problems with the Console I would have never found with debugging the code only.